# Печать каждой итерации при возведении в степень

Tags: многопоточность, c++

Здравствуйте!

Написал программу, возводящую матрицу в определенную степень через потоки. Возможно ли как-то печатать матрицы при каждой итерации с потоками? Т.е. если нужно в 3-ю степень возвести, то и вторую тоже нужно вывести на печать. С одним потоком всё просто и понятно, но с 2 и более уже возникают проблемы.

Может, здесь с событиями нужно работать или с синхронизацией потоков (хотя еще не до конца события и синхронизацию понял)?

```
unsigned __stdcall threadMult(void *param){

    int id = (int)param;

    Pow(matr_3, matr_1, N, POW, id);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    matr_1 = new int *[N];
    matr_3 = new int *[N];

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        matr_1[i] = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        matr_3[i] = new int[N];

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++)
            matr_1[i][j] = rand() % 3;

    PrintArray(matr_1, N);
    cout << endl;

    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();

    HANDLE hThreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    unsigned id;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
        hThreads[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadMult, (void *)i, 0, &id);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(NUMBER_OF_THREADS, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);

    PrintArray(matr_3, N);

    end = clock() - start;
    cout << endl << "runtime: " << end / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    cout << endl;

    DeleteArray(matr_1, N);
    DeleteArray(matr_3, N);

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**update:**

В main добавил

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
        hEvents[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
```

И изменил функцию:
    unsigned __stdcall threadMult(void *param){

```
    int id = (int)param;
    Pow(matr_3, matr_1, N, POW, id);
    SetEvent(hEvents[id]);
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[1 - id], INFINITE);
    PrintArray(matr_3, N);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Но выводит всё равно неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, Вы хотели бы произвести вывод промежуточных результатов возведения матрицы в степень. Вы должны понимать следующее :

1. Не получится выводить обрабатываемые разными потоками участки
   матрицы одновременно, так как поток вывода представляет собой единый
   разделяемый потоками ресурс, и если каждый поток попытается выводить
   свою часть матрицы без синхронизации с остальными, результатом будет
   бессмыслица.
2. Дописанный Вами в update код работать как Вы ожидаете не будет, так как:

   - в функции потоков Вы, по всей видимости, ожидаете, когда завершит вычисления поток с id на единицу меньше, но ожидаете почему-то установки события вот в такой ячейке `hEvents[1 - id]`, а если потоков, к примеру 4, получится обращение к ячейке массива `hEvents[-2]`;
   - в случае, если первым отработает поток, положим, с id = 1, а вторым - с id = 2, то, так как этот последний поток уже дождался отработки предыдущего, он преспокойно выведет свой вариант матрицы, не догадываясь, что поток с id = 0, который получил для обработки первые строки матрицы, еще не отработал и не заполнил свою часть общего результата.
3. Вывести промежуточный результат вычисления нескольких потоков в данном случае можно, если правильно синхронизировать их работу, однако, надо помнить, что эта синхронизация обязательно скажется на времени выполнения, так как она подразумевает, что одни потоки будут ожидать завершения работы других (такая вот последовательная параллельность :)). Следовательно, если Вы хотели сравнить время возведения в степень матрицы одним потоком и несколькими, эти замеры имеет смысл проделать после того, как: вы отладите программу с выводом на экран, убедитесь в ее работоспособности, и благополучно уберете оттуда этот вывод и всю связанную с ним логику, оставив только вычисления.
   Вот мои дополнения к коду, которые позволят синхронизировать потоки и вывести промежуточные результаты возведения в степень матрицы:

   - в `CreateEvent()` вторым параметром указываем TRUE, чтобы иметь возможность вручную сбрасывать события;
   - код функции потоков оставляем вот таким :

   ```
   unsigned __stdcall threadMult(void *param){
       int id = (int)param;
       Pow(matr_3, matr_1, N, POW, id);
       SetEvent(hEvents[id]);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   - в код функции возведения в степень матрицы добавляем синхронизацию: печатать
     матрицу на очередной итерации цикла будет только первый поток с id = 0, и только после того, как дождется завершения работы остальными потоками

   ```html
       void Pow(int **matr_3, int **matr_1, int L, int pow, int id){
       ...
         while (++p <= pow){
           ...
           if(NUMBER_OF_THREADS > 1){
             if(id == 0){
               // первый поток будет ждать завершения работы остальных, и печатать
               WaitForMultipleObjects((NUMBER_OF_THREADS-1), (const HANDLE *)&hEvents[1], TRUE, INFINITE);
               PrintArray(matr_3, N);
               cout << endl;
               // затем сообщит о готовности всем остальным
               PulseEvent(hEvents[0]);
             }
             else{
               //остальные - сообщают о готовности, и ждут, 
               // пока эти сообщения обработает первый
               SetEvent(hEvents[id]);
               WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], INFINITE);
               // и сбрасывают свои события
               ResetEvent(hEvents[id]);
             }
           }
           else{
             PrintArray(matr_3, N);
             cout << endl;
           }
         }
       }
   ```